# CASE statement after WHERE then one of several values can be NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have such select:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 Table Tb 
WHERE
 Tb.LastModificationDate BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
 AND Tb.var1 = @var1
 AND Tb.var2 = @var2
```

And its possible that @var1 and @var2 can be null (or only one of them) so for now I have 3 selects for each case (real select is more complicated so I am providing example for simplify things) I am try to merge them into one select with CASE but have no luck so far - as cant understand how to include AND clause in case if one of vars are not null.
I believe it should be something like that:

```
 SELECT 
  * 
 FROM 
  Table Tb 
 WHERE
  Tb.LastModificationDate BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
  (CASE WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL THEN (AND Tb.var1 = @var1)
        WHEN @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN (AND Tb.var2 = @var2)
  END);
```

any advice on that?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data or an plain language description of how you want this to behave? Strictly speaking  "AND Tb.var1 = var1
 AND Tb.var2 = var2" will evaluate false if either var1 or var2 is null. So that case logic is redundant. (Pretend there are "at" symbols in appropriate places, SO is mistaking those for user notifications)

Comment: Try: `... AND Tb.var1 = @var1 AND @var1 is NOT NULL  ...`   (no need for a `CASE WHEN .... ` )   But indeed the `AND !var1 IS not NULL1 is not needed.

Comment: @Error_2646: Type those expression between a back-quoot, and SO wil leave them alone.

Comment: It's better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Error_2646 francly speaking if var1 not null output include only columns where var1 column have value that is given, same for var2 if they both not provided then need output all from columns of var1 and var2

Comment: @jarlh how to use AND if operand can be null?

Comment: `(Tb.var1 = @var1 OR @var1 IS NULL)`, standard procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `CASE` statement, you would need to remove the `AND` clause from the `THEN` portion and move it to outside of `CASE` so that the result is evaluated. This is because `CASE` can not append the criteria to the `WHERE` clause (`THEN AND`).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Table Tb 
WHERE Tb.LastModificationDate BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
AND (CASE 
    WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL THEN Tb.var1 = @var1
    WHEN @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN Tb.var2 = @var2
END);
```

However, the above approach will be limited to the first "`CASE @var* IS NOT NULL`" that evaluates as true. So if both `@var1` and `@var2` are supplied, the CASE will only return `Tb.var1 = @var1`, and will **not** compare `Tb.var2 = @var2`.
To retrieve a result when both `@var1` and `@var2` are `NULL`, `ELSE true` would need to added to the `CASE` statement.

```sql
(CASE 
    WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL THEN Tb.var1 = @var1
    WHEN @var2 IS NOT NULL THEN Tb.var2 = @var2
    ELSE true
END);
```

---

Another approach that circumvents the first case limitation, would be to apply the criteria directly to the `WHERE` clause by using `AND (IS NULL OR ...)`.

This will allow for the criteria to match under the following 4 conditions:

1. Not checked if both `@var1` and `@var2` are `NULL`
2. `@var1` if supplied (`Tb.var1 = @var1`)
3. `@var2` if supplied (`Tb.var2 = @var2`)
4. `@var1` and `@var2` if both are supplied (`Tb.var1 = @var1 AND Tb.var2 = @var2`)

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Table Tb 
WHERE Tb.LastModificationDate BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
AND (@var1 IS NULL OR Tb.var1 = @var1)
AND (@var2 IS NULL OR Tb.var2 = @var2);
```

Working Examples: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PneRnMjrMPXjg35NsH2LE/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
Table Tb 
WHERE
Tb.LastModificationDate BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
AND ((@var1 IS NOT NULL AND Tb.var1 = @var1) 
OR
    (@var2 IS NOT NULL AND Tb.var2 = @var2));
```

I would have done this way.

Answer (score 1):

Check for both `@var1` and `@var2` if they are `NULL` **or** equal to the value of a column:

```
 WHERE Tb.LastModificationDate BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
   AND (@var1 IS NULL OR Tb.var1 = @var1)
   AND (@var2 IS NULL OR Tb.var2 = @var2)
```